# Custom CheckBox with default style

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, material-design, android-custom-view

I need to create a custom CheckBox with default material style.

My class is defined like so

```
class CustomCheckBox @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : CheckBox(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

}
```

If I look at the default CheckBox's properties they have the following attributes defined

```
background: @android:drawable/control_background_40pd_material
button: @android:drawable/btn_check_material_anim
```

but the derived widget does not have them.

How can I apply these to the derived class?

**Update**

I've tried to extend `MaterialCheckBox` and the default attributes are now shown in the panel, but it gives an exception

```
IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app 
theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant)
```

I'm not using `Material` theme, so how can I make the default background and button drawable be applied to the custom class?

Comment: Did you try to extends from AppCompatCheckbox or the checkbox in the material library?

Comment: The default CheckBox I refered to is defined in the layout as `<CheckBox/>`. I've also tried to extend `AppCompatCheckbox` and `MaterialCheckBox` but nothing changed.

Comment: I've just tried to clean the project and extend from `MaterialCheckBox` again and now it does have the default attributes set but now it shows an error. See Udate in the question

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `@JvmOverloads` is the root of the problem as described in [this post](https://medium.com/@mmlodawski/https-medium-com-mmlodawski-do-not-always-trust-jvmoverloads-5251f1ad2cfe)

I replaced it by

```
constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

and now it works as expected.